# How can I sort a lookup drop-down list box in the Edit or Create form?

Tags: infopath, list-view, lookup-column, form, dropdown

I've been developing a SharePoint site to track projects and work intakes at my job, and one thing that I can't figure out is how to sort the contents of a lookup drop-down list box.

The data I'm trying to sort is;

***Timeframe Title***

- *Math: 8/1/2016*
- *Science*: 8/1/2016
- *Science*: 8/15/2016
- *Science*: 8/29/2016
- *Math*: 8/15/2016
- *Social Studies*: 8/15/2016
- ...

I'd like to sort it alphabetically so that each unique department appears together.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `lookup column` in a SharePoint list automatically sorted by the `alphabetic` values in `ascending order`

If you need to customize ordering based on special order at Edit and Create Form I think you can't do it as out of the box solution, and you need to customize your forms via InfoPath as mentioned [here](http://www.sharepointbreak.com/2013/08/22/sort-sharepoint-lookup-column-combo-box-by-customizing-your-list-form-with-infopath/)

Regarding your views you can sort it alphabetically so that each unique department appears together  you should follow the mentioned steps below :

- From the above list ribbon, select modify view   >

[image]

From the same page chek Beside Group by Select The department Name Column to group by it and to sort it as

- Show groups in ascending order
- Show groups in descending order

[image]
You can also create your custom view from

> List setting > Scroll down to the below of the page > click create view > and sort as you want.

[image]

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification :)